# Error when using 'sudo pacman -Syu' in Antergos

Tags: pacman, antergos

Whenever I try to update my packages in Antergos using sudo pacman -Syu it does not work. It starts updated the packages for a minute or two, then comes up with a bunch of error messages (so many that it goes past how much I can scroll up) saying things such as:

```
gnome-getting-started-docs: /usr/share/help/pl/gnome-help/gs-web-browser1.svg already exists in filesystem
```

or

```
gnome-getting-started-docs: /usr/share/help/ko/gnome-help/figures/gnome-responding-to-messages.webm exists in filesystem
```

After those it simply says that there were errors and the packages couldn't be upgraded. What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: I would go with backuping these files and then removing them. Then try to update again. As you didn't posted the whole trace there little I can help you with.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#.22Failed_to_commit_transaction_.28conflicting_files.29.22_error